# Windows Device Paths - difference between //?/ and //./ prefixes?

Tags: windows, winapi, wdk, unc, user32

While trying to figure out how to 'match up' the menagerie of identifiers I can get from the Windows API for video adapters and monitors, I came across a question that I haven't been able to find an answer to.

Two of the identifiers I can query for have what looks like a DOS device or UNC prefix:

**Device Interface Name:**

```
\\?\DISPLAY#Default_Monitor#1&c528b8a&0&UID256#{e6f07b5f-ee97-4a90-b076-33f57bf4eaa7}
```

**Device Name:**

```
\\.\DISPLAY70\Monitor0
```

These examples are likely from different devices, but note the different prefixes; **`\\?\`** vs. **`\\.\`**

[Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats) doesn't specifically state that these two prefixes are *identical*, though it seems that's implied.

Is this simply a matter of old-DOS-style vs new-UNC-style, or do these two prefixes have different meanings?

Comment: https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2016/02/the-definitive-guide-on-win32-to-nt.html

Comment: *Root Local Device path. This is any path that begins with the characters \\?\ and acts as an escape into the object manager. It’s almost exactly the same as the Local Device path ( \\.\ ) type with one crucial difference: no **canonicalization** of the path is done*

Comment: Thank you @RbMm, that's exactly what I wanted to know. :-)